Continuous time Markov Processes, transition rate matrix Q
I have these lecture notes on continuous time Markov Processes: CTMPs 
I don't seem to understand the relation $Q=P'(0)$, for P: the transition probability matric and Q: the transition rate matrix.
Usually, we start with $P(0)=Id$, where Id is the identity matrix. But wouldn't that imply that Q is always $0$?
Here is my logic: 
When $P(0)=Id$, we only have $0$s and $1$s in the matrix, so then $\frac{d}{dt} 1 = \frac{d}{dt} 0 = 0$. 
So I don't get how do we get a nonzero matrix Q.
I would appreciate any help how to grasp this.

Suppose, for example, that $P(t)=I+At$. Then $P(0)=I$, but $P'(0)=A\neq 0$.
